# laravel RuntimeException in EncryptionServiceProvider.php line 29: No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid

Tags: php, laravel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYdxG.png)I've been getting this error even though I changed the app key and also The cipher.

RuntimeException in EncryptionServiceProvider.php line 29:
No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.

is there any solution, please .

Comment: try `php artisan:key generate`

Comment: i already did . but i got the same problem

Comment: chek if you have `Mbstring PHP Extension`, try `phpinfo()` and check it

Comment: you need to do `phpinfo()` somewhere in your code and have to run it

Comment: i 'm not quite sure where i should put it . i'm sorry i'm just a beginner.

Comment: How do you run your app now?

Comment: you mean by terminal ?

Comment: You see `server.php` file or `index.php`? add `phpinfo();` after `<?php` and run your app

Comment: you are using windows or linux?

Comment: I'm using os x .

Comment: check your php.ini file and search for `extension=php_mbstring.dll`

Comment: or run this command `sudo port install php5-mbstring`

Comment: i didn't find it so i should install it ?

Comment: i got port command not found

Comment: is it okay if i'm using php 7.0.15 ?

Comment: did you see anything like `extension=php_mbstring` in your `php.ini`?

Comment: no i didn't find

Comment: you are using Xampp or Mamp?

Comment: i'm using mamp  .

Comment: i have a question . why is that i got diffrent error when i open the project in localhost:8888 and 8000

Comment: what is that other error?

Comment: InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:
View [portal.index] not found. and i've checked the name and they are correct .

Comment: It should have .blade.php extention

Comment: is it in app.php ?

Comment: Where do you have `portal.index`?

Comment: in my views folder

Comment: post screenshot of your views folder

Comment: i posted the picture

Comment: okay i will  check

Comment: "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here " i can't use chat

Comment: yes i can see the message

Comment: i sent you a mail

Answer (score 0):

These are mandatory extension for laravel to run properly

```
 -PHP >= 5.5.9
 -OpenSSL PHP Extension
 -PDO PHP Extension
 -Mbstring PHP Extension
 -Tokenizer PHP Extension
```

Make sure you have this all